# Como trocar o idioma do Git para inglês no Linux?

Tags: linux, git

Estou utilizando o Git no terminal do Linux (Ubuntu),  e ele está em português.

> No ramo master
>
> Submissão inicial.
>
> nada para enviar (crie/copie arquivos e use "git add" para registrar)

Como consigo trocar as configurações do Git de idioma, para inglês?

Comment: Por curiosidade, isto atrapalha em algo?

Comment: me incomoda um pouco,  e como eu já entendo portugues, estudando git em ingles ajuda a me adaptar aos termos e etc.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Altere o `~/.bashrc`:

```
alias git='LANG=en_US git'
```

Comment: Obrigado bigown, funcionou.